# List of const int instead of enum

Tags: c#, design-patterns, enums

I started working on a large c# code base and found the use of a static class with several const ints fields. This class is acting exactly like an enum would.

I would like to convert the class to an actual enum, but the powers that be said no. The main reason I would like to convert it is so that I could have the enum as the data type instead of int. This would help a lot with readability.

Is there any reason to not use enums and to use const ints instead?
This is currently how the code is:

```
public int FieldA { get; set; }
public int FieldB { get; set; }

public static class Ids
{
    public const int ItemA = 1;
    public const int ItemB = 2;
    public const int ItemC = 3;
    public const int ItemD = 4;
    public const int ItemE = 5;
    public const int ItemF = 6;
}
```

However, I think it should be the following instead:

```
public Ids FieldA { get; set; }
public Ids FieldB { get; set; }
```

Comment: Using a data type instead of an int will also prevent any possible errors that the compiler can pick up.

Comment: Without knowing the *purpose* of those fields and constants it's very hard to come up with a reasonable answer that would provide a quality, specific architectural advice.

Comment: Why don't you ask “the powers that be”?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I think many of the answers here ignore the implications of the semantics of `enums`.**

- You should consider using an enum when the entire set of all valid values (Ids) is known in advance, and is small enough to be declared in program code.
- You should consider using an int when the set of known values is a *subset* of all the possible values - and the code only needs to be aware of this subset.

With regards to refactoring - when time and business contraints allow, it's a good idea to clean code up when the new design/implementation has clear benefit over the previous implementation and where the risk is well understood. In situations where the benefit is low or the risk is high (or both) it may be better to take the position of **"do no harm"**  rather than **"continuously improve"**. Only you are in a position to judge which case applies to your situation.

By the way, a case where **neither** enums *or* constant ints are necessarily a good idea is when the IDs represent the identifiers of records in an external store (like a database). It's often risky to hardcode such IDs in the program logic, as these values may actually be different in different environments (eg. Test, Dev, Production, etc). In such cases, loading the values at runtime may be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: +1. This is probably the most complete answer possible, without knowing more about how these fields are used.

Comment: The core problem I am seeing in the code is that the data type is int in several places when it really should be the enum value. Thus, I can see large problems in the future when invalid values are passed in.

Comment: @Telavian: As I said, if there is a known set of values which represent the only possible valid values for these fields, then an `enum` may be the way to go. But if some of the values may be acquired and passed in at runtime, then an enum is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Your suggested solution looks elegant, but won't work as it stands, as you can't use instances of a static type. It's a bit trickier than that to emulate an enum.

There are a few possible reasons for choosing enum or const-int for the implementation, though I can't think of many strong ones for the actual example you've posted - on the face of it, it seems an ideal candidate for an enum.

A few ideas that spring to mind are:

**Enums**

- They provide type-safety. You can't pass any old number where an enum value is required.
- Values can be autogenerated
- You can use reflection to easily convert between the 'values' and 'names'
- You can easily enumerate the values in an enum in a loop, and then if you add new enum members the loop will automatically take them into account.
- You can insert new enunm values without worrying about clashes occurring if you accidentally repeat a value.

**const-ints**

- If you don't understand how to use enums (e.g. not knowing how to change the underlying data type of an enum, or how to set explicit values for enum values, or how to assign the same value to mulitple constants) you might mistakenly believe you're achieving something you can't use an enum for, by using a const.
- If you're used to other languages you may just naturally approach the problem with consts, not realising that a better solution exists.
- You can derive from classes to extend them, but annoyingly you can't derive a new enum from an existing one (which would be a really useful feature). Potentially you could therefore use a class (but not the one i your example!) to achieve an "extendable enum".
- You can pass ints around easily. Using an enum may require you to be constantly casting (e.g.) data you receive from a database to and from the enumerated type. What you lose in type-safety you gain in convenience. At least until you pass the wrong number somewhere... :-)
- If you use readonly rather than const, the values are stored in actual memory locations that are read when needed. This allows you to publish constants to another assembly that are read and used at runtime, rather than built into the other assembly, which means that you don't have to recompile the dependant assembly when you change any of the constants in your own assembly. This is an important consideration if you want to be able to patch a large application by just releasing updates for one or two assemblies.
- I guess it is a way of making it clearer that the enum values *must* stay unchanged. With an enum another programmer will just drop in a new value without thinking, but a list of consts makes you stop and think "why is it like this? How do I add a new value safely?". But I'd achieve this by putting explicit values on the enums and adding a clear comment, rather than resorting to consts.

**Why should you leave the implementation alone?**

- The code may well have been written by an idiot who has no good reason for what he did. But changing his code and showing him he's an idiot isn't a smart or helpful move.
- There may be a good reason it's like that, and you will break something if you change it (e.g. it may need to be a class due to being accessed through reflection, being exposed through external interfaces, or to stop people easily serializing the values because they'll be broken by the obfuscation system you're using). No end of unnecessary bugs are introduced into systems by people who don't fully understand how something works, especially if they don't know how to test their changes to ensure they haven't broken anything.
- The class may be autogenerated by an external tool, so it is the tool you need to fix, not the source code.
- There may be a plan to do something more with that class in future (?!)
- Even if it's safe to change, you will have to re-test everything that is affected by the change. If the code works as it stands, is the gain worth the pain? When working on legacy systems we will often see existing code of poor quality or just done a way we don't personally like, and we have to accept that it is not cost effective to "fix" it, no matter how much it niggles. Of course, you may also find yourself biting back an "I told you so!" when the const-based implementation fails due to lacking type-safety. But aside from type-safety, the implementation is ultimately no less efficient or effective than an enum.

Answer (score 1):

If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

I don't know the design of the system you're working on, but I suspect that the fields are integers that just happen to have a number of predefined values. That's to say they could, in some future state, contain more than those predefined values. While an `enum` allows for that scenario (via casting), it implies that only the values the enumeration contains are valid.

Overall, the change is a semantic one but it is unnecessary. Unnecessary changes like this are often a source of bugs, additional test overhead and other headaches with only mild benefits. I say add a comment expressing that this could be an `enum` and leave it as it is.

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it leads to technical debt. I agree that there are pros and cons here but I don't know how you can be in a position to deliver judgement on the trade off.

Comment: @David: If it's a large code base, I expect there is much technical debt. This isn't leading to it, it already exists. However, choosing to spend effort fixing that is a big choice and one that, given my experience, is never going to outweigh the need to spend money on bug fixes and new features. Changing this code is going to possibly (and it isn't guaranteed) fix one small area of technical debt but could very easily break a lot - that's an expensive decision. Without any compelling reason presented in the question, I passed my judgement and I stand by it.

Comment: If you can't make this change for fear of introducing bugs, then you need better tests. If your tests can't cope with this then your technical debt is going to mount up pretty rapidly.

Comment: @David: It's not about whether the tests can cope with it. Changing even simple code can have unforeseen consequences. With the given information (large code base, for example), I'd say even a small change could be dangerous. It's unnecessary from what has been told to us here and therefore, should be avoided. 100% test coverage would be wonderful, but that's not exactly common - if you've invented 100% bug free development methods, you should get rich and famous quickly.

Comment: My take on this is that if you are scared to make a small change like this then your code is ill and needs urgent attention. If you can't foresee all the consequences here then you are in big trouble.

Comment: @David: I would agree, but from what we have been told, the OP doesn't have that knowledge of the system, but we might assume the "powers that be" do and they said "no, don't change it".

Also, fear isn't the only thing at play. It still takes budget to make this change.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3280/discussion-between-jeff-yates-and-david-heffernan)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does help with readability, and no I cannot think of any reason against it.

Using const int is a very common "old school" of programming practice for C++.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I see is that if you want to be loosely coupled with another system that uses the same constants, you avoid being tightly coupled and share the same enum type.

Like in RPC calls or something...

Comment: You can just convert the `enum` to an `int` for those calls. That's not a reason not to use the `enum` inside one application.

Comment: if a rpc or a low level call returns an int, indeed you can use enums in your "program space". In fact it would be clearer on your side and it would break if the 2 entities talking to each other are not synchronized. It goes both way, not just converting _your_ enum to an int but the int you receive to an enum.